# Регулярное выражение. Перевод строки.

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Привет,
В textarea вводится стих. Как определить номера позиций всех переводов строки на Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txtarea').value.replace('\r', '');
var txtar = txt.split('\n');
//а далее - работаем с txtar[i].length
```

Вариант с поправкой на IE7 (спасибо AlexWindHope):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txtarea').value.replace('\r', '');
var txtar = txt.split('\n');
//а далее - работаем с (txtar[i].indexOf('\r') ? txtar[i].length-1 : txtar[i].length)
```

Comment: value.replace('\r', '') - не работает в некоторых 7ых IE (звучит странно это так).

Причиной тому является то что IE, как только символ очиститься посдтавляет его сам

Comment: И много ли этих бажных осликов? Если много, то можно сразу делать `split()`, а потом работать с `txtar[i].indexOf('\r')+1 ? txtar[i].length-1 : txtar[i].length` .

Comment: Спасибо! работает. Такое изящное решение.
объясните, пожалуйста, зачем нужно менять перевод каретки на пустоту?

Comment: @ling - на многих вистах по умолчанию. Не то что бы пользователей висты сейчас много, но, собственно не так и мало

Comment: @Irinkes, это связано с различным способом переноса строки в Windows и Linux (или ASCII и Unicode, не помню уже). Дело в том, что где-то он кодируется `\r\n`, а где-то `\n`.
@AlexWindHope, спасибо за замечание. Сейчас допишу второй вариант.

Answer (score 2):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txtarea').match(/[^\r]+/);
nums = new Array();
pos = 0;
for (i_line = 0; i_line < txt.length; i_line++) {
    pos += txt[i_line].length;
    nums.push((++pos) + ":" + txt[i_line]);
};
// nums содержит номера позиций и строки разделенные знаком :
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться